# Find minimal length of sub-array whose sum is greater than K

Tags: c++, algorithm

How can I find sub-array qualifying that its sum is greater than a given `K`?

What I came up with is maintain to pointer at the start and end of the sequence, and incrementally subtract the smaller one to shorten the sequence. But seems it's invalid. Why?

Here is my implmentation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (!cin.eof()) {
        int caseCount;
        cin >> caseCount;
        int N, S;
        for (int i = 0; i < caseCount; i++) {
            cin >> N >> S;
            int * seq = new int[N];
            int maxSum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
                cin >> seq[j];
                maxSum += seq[j];
            }
            if (maxSum < S) {
                cout << 0 << endl;
                continue;
            }
            int left, right;
            left = 0;
            right = N-1;
            while(left < right) {
                if(seq[left] < seq[right]) {
                    if (maxSum - seq[left] < S) {
                        cout << right-left+1 << endl;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        maxSum -= seq[left];
                        left++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (maxSum - seq[right] < S) {
                        cout << right-left+1 << endl;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        maxSum -= seq[right];
                        right--;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (left >= right) {
                cout << 1 << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Input:

```
2 // amount of sequences to input
10 15 // sequence 1 length and K
5 1 3 5 10 7 4 9 2 8 // sequence 1 data
5 11 // sequence 2 length and K
1 2 3 4 5 // sequence 2 data
```

Sample Output:

```
2
3
```

Comment: Did you mean minimal length sub-array?

Comment: Please delete[] seq at some point

Comment: Are expensive but easy to understand solutions allowed? As in: 1) read whole sequence, 2) generate set of all sub-sequences, 3) filter out elements with sum ≤ K, 4) find shortest sub-sequence?

Comment: @Kay I wish it's as efficient as possible.

Comment: In a standard C++ application you shouldn't need pointers nowadays.

Comment: what do the numbers in "sample output" mean? are they indices? are they numbers to be summed? which sum are they the answer for? is the sample input multiple lists or only one?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen they are the length of the subarray. This is obviously a programming question from an "Online Judge", which the OP is cheating by getting SO to do his code for him. Sources: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3562 & https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=679

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is incorrect. You basically only check middle of the sequence, which doesn't make any sense. Instead you should start with both indexes at the beginning of the array and increment right as long as sum of subrange is smaller than K. When it gets bigger start incrementing left until it is smaller again. Now you have a candidate for your shortest subsequence - save it. Repeat until right won't get past the end of array, updating your candidate if new one is shorter.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I believe your code belongs in your own answer, because it's not exactly what aryjczyk described; also, it's rather inefficient!

Comment: And you even added python code to his answer to a question tagged as C++...

Comment: Rollbacked his edit, I provided only algorithm description on purpose - it is a homework-like question. And I think there was a bug in it ;)

Comment: i didn't read it too closely, but while advancing left you were using >= K, so if sequence included zeros, they would also end up in the sub-sequence

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea in Python (since it's mostly an algorithmic question), assuming your inputs are natural numbers (thanks @ChrisOkasaki). It operates on `list`s, but it should be easy to adjust for your purpose. Both `start` and `end` are inclusive. It returns both the first and the last index of the sub-array.

```
def find_minimal_length_subarr(arr, min_sum):
    found = False
    start = end = cur_start = cur_end = 0
    cur_sum = arr[cur_start]
    while cur_end < len(arr):
        if cur_start < cur_end:
            cur_sum += arr[cur_end]
        while cur_sum-arr[cur_start] >= min_sum:
            cur_sum -= arr[cur_start]
            cur_start += 1
        if cur_sum >= min_sum and (not found or cur_end-cur_start < end-start):
            start, end = cur_start, cur_end
            found = True
        cur_end += 1
    if found:
        return start, end

print find_minimal_length_subarr([11, 2, 3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8], 21) # (6, 8)
```

It starts from the beginning and expands to the right while the `min_sum` is not reached. When reached, it shortens from the left while `min_sum` is still reached. Then it continues to expand again. Only if a better (shorter) candidate is found, an earlier is replaced. Time complexity is O(n), space complexity O(1).

Comment: Negative numbers will break this.  For example, [1,-4,5,3,3].

Comment: @ChrisOkasaki Could you spot the error? At first glance, I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: With the [1,-4,5,3,3] example, I meant to include a limit of 7.  The outer loop will advance cur_end to the *second* 3 before starting to advance cur_start, which makes it impossible to find the [5,3] subarray.

Comment: @ChrisOkasaki OK, I can't think of a quick fix, so I'll just make this assumption.

Comment: That handles when the negative drops the sum below 0, but try [8,-7,5,5,4] and 12.

Comment: @ChrisOkasaki I tried a couple approaches as you can see in the edit history, but then reverted to this solution and the remark. I just couldn't get it quite right and don't feel like putting in more effort, especially now it's obvious that the OP doesn't require it anyway.

Comment: find_minimal_length_subarr([1,-2,10,-7,8,-7,8], 11).  I'm sure this is fixable, but going in this direction would probably give you O(N^2), if you're not there already.

Comment: [-12, 2, 2, -12, 2, 0], 4 already caused problems. I'm considering opening a question myself, because I'm starting to wonder if this is at all possible in linear time...

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example in C++ based on Thijs algorithm, which seems like the ideal algorithm for your problem (if we understood it correctly. It can be changed easily to find *the first* subsequence or *all* subsequences matching the predicate)

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template<typename It>
pair<It, It> subseq_with_sum_greater(It begin, It end, typename It::value_type barrier)
{
    typename It::value_type current_sum = 0;
    pair<It, It> res = make_pair(begin, end);
    for(It current = begin; current < end; ++current)
    {
        current_sum += *current;
        while(current_sum > barrier and current_sum - *begin > barrier)
            current_sum -= *begin++;
        if(current_sum > barrier and distance(begin, current) < distance(res.first, res.second))
            res = make_pair(begin, current);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {5, 1, 3, 5, 10, 7, 4, 9, 2, 8};
    auto subseq = subseq_with_sum_greater(v.begin(), v.end(), 15);
    cout << distance(v.begin(), subseq.first) << ", " << distance(v.begin(), subseq.second);
}
```

And the output is `4, 5`, the indexes of the subsequence. Please note that using `std::distance` is O(1) complexity only with RandomAccess iterators (like those on std::vector), you may want to add `size_t current_distance, minimal_distance` variables if you want to use this kind of template on other containers. Also, when not finding any subsequence, this algorithm returns a `begin, end` pair, which makes it difficult to know if this is the answer or if no subsequence match. depending on your case, you may want to have a more precise output.

Comment: on `v={2, 2, 3, 2}, barrier=3`  the output is `0, 1`. that can't be right...

Comment: Outputs the indexes of the subsequence [2, 2], which is right because you need two numbers to be *strictly* greater than 3 in your exmple... But you're right that is not very C++ like, you may prefer the algorithm to output 0, 2 for this subsequence (interval open on the right). The `++current`instruction can be placed out of the for, before the if, to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with negative content too:

```
def s(arr, K):
   candidate = None
   for l,r in [(x,x+1) for x in range(len(arr))]:
     while sum(arr[l:r]) < K and r <= len(arr): r = r + 1
     if K <= sum(arr[l:r]):
       if candidate is None or r-l < candidate[1]-candidate[0]:
         candidate = (l,r)
   return candidate # ending index will be exclusive
```

In C++:

```
typedef struct {
    bool found; int l; int r; 
} range;

int sum(int arr[], int arr_n, int l, int r) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=l; i<r && i<arr_n; i++)
        sum+=arr[i];
    return sum;
}

range s(int arr[], int K, int arr_n) {
    bool found = false; int c_l; int c_r;
    for (int l=0; l<arr_n; l++) {
        int r = l+1;
        while (sum(arr, arr_n, l, r) < K && r <= arr_n) r++;
        if (K <= sum(arr, arr_n, l, r))
            if (!found || r-l < c_r-c_l) {
                c_l = l; c_r = r; found = true;
            }
    }
    return (range){found, c_l, c_r};
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it has O(n^2) time complexity.