# Finding a minimal subarray of n integers of sum >= k in linear time

Tags: python, algorithm

Recently I've been struggling with the following problem:

Given an array of integers, find a minimal (shortest length) subarray that sums to at least k.

Obviously this can easily be done in O(n^2). I was able to write an algorithm that solves it in linear time for natural numbers, but I can't figure it out for integers.

My latest attempt was this:

```
def find_minimal_length_subarr_z(arr, min_sum):
    found = False
    start = end = cur_end = cur_sum = 0
    for cur_start in range(len(arr)):
        if cur_end <= cur_start:
            cur_end, cur_sum = cur_start, arr[cur_start]
        else:
            cur_sum -= arr[cur_start-1]
        # Expand
        while cur_sum < min_sum and cur_end < len(arr)-1:
            cur_end += 1
            cur_sum += arr[cur_end]
        # Contract
        while cur_end > cur_start:
            new_sum = cur_sum - arr[cur_end]
            if new_sum >= min_sum or new_sum >= cur_sum:
                cur_end -= 1
                cur_sum = new_sum
            else:
                break
        if cur_sum >= min_sum and (not found or cur_end-cur_start < end-start):
            start, end, found = cur_start, cur_end, True
    if found:
        return start, end
```

For example:

```
[8, -7, 5, 5, 4], 12 => (2, 4)
```

However, it fails for:

```
[-12, 2, 2, -12, 2, 0], 4
```

where the correct result is `(1, 2)` but the algorithm doesn't find it.

Can this at all be done in linear time (with preferably constant space complexity)?

Comment: Are you looking for a general algorithm or something Python-specific?

Comment: @arshajii General algorithm is fine, as long as it's not in a language that makes it hard to understand/translate, such as Haskell.

Comment: to give it a name: isn't it the Kadane's Algorithm but terminated prematurely?

Comment: One thing to note is that you'll never want to start the subarray with a negative number.

Comment: @VaughnCato I made quite a few observations, such as that it doesn't make sense to have any sequence that has a negative sum (stronger version of your statement), but in the end it was all fixing a few corner cases. In the end, there was always a way to break it, so now I'm looking for a more structural way of solving it.

Comment: @redreggae Not sure if Kadane can be adjusted to return the shortest one.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien you're right. I ignored this fact..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379047/find-minimal-length-of-sub-array-whose-sum-is-greater-than-k

Comment: @Artur Yes, that's the question that led to this one; it only concerned natural numbers.

Comment: 1) Find the smallest element and add that element to all the elements. Now you have only natural elements. (Your solution work on this). You just have to modify and ask for sum_min + cnt * MIN_VALUE, where cnt is the number of elements that you are using in the solution.

Comment: @IonescuRobert: It's not clear that that makes it any easier.

Comment: @IonescuRobert While it seemed like a good idea at first, in fact it doesn't work (with my algorithm) because `sum_min` changes all the time, so the problem essentially remains the same: I can't decide when to expand to the right or contract from the left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one that's linear time but also linear space.  The extra space comes from a deque that could grow to linear size.  (There's also a second array to maintain cumulative sums, but that could be removed pretty easily.)

```
from collections import deque
def find_minimal_length_subarr(arr, k):
   # assume k is positive
   sumBefore = [0]
   for x in arr: sumBefore.append(sumBefore[-1] + x)
   bestStart = -1
   bestEnd = len(arr)
   startPoints = deque()
   start = 0
   for end in range(len(arr)):
      totalToEnd = sumBefore[end+1]
      while startPoints and totalToEnd - sumBefore[startPoints[0]] >= k: # adjust start
         start = startPoints.popleft()
      if totalToEnd - sumBefore[start] >= k and end-start < bestEnd-bestStart:
         bestStart,bestEnd = start,end
      while startPoints and totalToEnd <= sumBefore[startPoints[-1]]: # remove bad candidates
         startPoints.pop()
      startPoints.append(end+1) # end+1 is a new candidate
   return (bestStart,bestEnd)
```

The deque holds a sequence of candidate start positions from left to right.  The key invariant is that positions in the deque are also sorted by increasing value of "sumBefore".

To see why, consider two positions x and y with x > y, and suppose sumBefore[x] <= sumBefore[y].  Then x is a strictly better start position than y (for segments ending at x or later), so we need never consider y again.

FURTHER EXPLANATION:

Imagine a naive algorithm that looked like this:

```
for end in 0..N-1
   for start in 0..end
      check the segment from start to end
```

I'm try to improve the inner loop to only consider certain start points instead of all possible start points.  So when can we eliminate a particular start point from further consideration?  In two situations.  Consider two start points S0 and S1 with S0 to the left of S1.

First, we can eliminate S0 if we ever find that S1 begins an eligible segment (that is, a segment summing to at least k).  That's what the first while loop does, where start is S0 and startPoints[0] is S1.  Even if we found some future eligible segment starting at S0, it would be longer than the segment we already found starting at S1.

Second, we can eliminate S0 if the sum of the elements from S0 to S1-1 is <= 0 (or, equivalently if the sum of the elements before S0 >= the sum of the elements before S1).  This is what the second while loop does, where S0 is startPoints[-1] and S1 is end+1.  Trimming off the elements from S0 to S1-1 always makes sense (for end points at S1 or later), because it makes the segment shorter without decreasing its sum.

Actually, there's a third situation where we could eliminate S0: when the distance from S0 to end is greater than the length of the shortest segment found so far.  I didn't implement this case because it wasn't needed.

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more? I'm missing the general idea.

Comment: @VaughnCato: that would be because I flipped my explanation.  I meant x > y, not x < y.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: added more explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your input regarding this problem (also in the other question).

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a pseudo-code delivering the solution you are looking for.

```
curIndex = 0
while (curIndex <= endIndex)
{
    if(curSum == 0)
    {
        startIndex = curIndex
    }

    curSum = curSum + curVal
    curTot = curTot + 1
    if(curSum >= targetVal AND curTot < minTotSofar)
    { 
        maxSumSofar = curSum
        maxStartIndex = startIndex
        maxEndIndex = curIndex
        minTotSofar = curTot
        if(curTot == 1)
        {
            exit_loop
        }

        curSum = 0
        curTot = 0
        curIndex = startIndex   
    }
    else if(curIndex == endIndex)
    {
        if(maxSumSofar == 0 AND curSum >= targetValue)
        {
                maxSumSofar = curSum
                maxStartIndex = startIndex
                maxEndIndex = curIndex
                minTotSofar = curTot
         }
         else if(curSum < targetValue AND startIndex < endIndex)
         {
                curSum = 0
                curTot = 0
                curIndex = startIndex
         }
    }
    curIndex = curIndex + 1
}
```

------------ UPDATE AFTER JWPAT7 SUGGESTION

INPUTS: array of integers, indexed from 0 to `endIndex`. Target value (k) to compare with (`targetVal`).

OUTPUTS: final addition of the chosen subset (`maxSumSoFar`), start index of the subset (`maxStartIndex`), end index of the subset (`maxEndIndex`), total number of elements in the subset (`minTotSofar`).

Comment: It isn't clear what result the code produces, or what its inputs are.  Perhaps you could add a procedure heading to show inputs and a return-results statement to clarify those points.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code right now. Let me know if further clarifications are required.

Comment: Originally, I wrongly wrote a code looking for subsets <= k. That's why all these corrections. This version should be fine. Apologies for all the problems

Comment: Really, the solution to @VaughnCato's problem is `(2, 3)`, because that's the shortest subarray with sum >= 8.

Comment: You are right. My bad: pretty tired today and wrote my answer without thinking about it too much. But the algorithm delivers the right solution. Bear in min that I created the algorithm directly in pseudocode, there is no working program in any language.

Comment: It's a bit hard to put that all in a comment.  I implemented your algorithm in python and tried it.  There are a few things that were left out of the pseudocode which I may have implemented incorrectly.  I'll try to give more details in a later comment.

Comment: The algorithm wasn't accounting for all the situations. I have performed the required corrections and now should work without any problem.